# Rewriting rules in Nginx

Tags: regex, nginx

How can I serve my static files

```
http://example.com/website/product.html
```

as

```
http://example.com/product
```

in nginx conf file

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better method for serving your static files: Using CENTOS, NGINX 1.10.0 Ubuntu

• Create a CNAME in your zone records: e.g. static.example.com

• In your NGINX domain configuration file (e.g. /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default), add a server block that looks something like:

```
server {
    listen         80;
    listen    [::]:80;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.php;

    server_name    static.example.com;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

• Restart NGINX Service and PHP:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart nginx.service
$ sudo systemctl restart php7.0-fpm.service
```

• Adjust the URLs for all your static files: e.g. http://static.example.com/js/my_javascript.js